# LinqToDB.LinqToDBException Expressionis not an association

Tags: c#

Hi All I am trying to do below ,I want to load an attribute value like this .

```
var date = db.GetTable<bbb>().Where(x => idList.Contains(x.MID))
                        .Select(x => x.ModifiedDate).FirstOrDefault;

var test = db.GetTable<nnn>().Where(x => xguy.Distinct().Contains(x.SID))
                        .LoadWith(x => x.Modified == lastPostDate);
```

exception:-

> LinqToDB.LinqToDBException: 'Expression '(x.Modified == value(vv.x+<>c__DisplayClass25_1).lastPostDate)' is not an association.'

How can I do this?

I used the FirstOrDefault option to get one value, but I do not understand about Expression is not an association.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of the "LoadWith" method is suspicious here.

[LoadWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.loadwith?view=netframework-4.8.1) is a specialized function to load additional table data that is linked (e.g. via foreign key) to the current table row.

Based on your usage, it looks like you're just trying to set up another "Where" clause, so instead of

```cs
.LoadWith(x => x.Modified == lastPostDate);
```

you wanted

```cs
.Where(x => x.Modified == lastPostDate);
```

or alternatively, combine this with your prior `Where` statement to simplify things:

```cs
var test = db.GetTable<nnn>().Where(x => x.Modified == lastPostDate &&
                                         xguy.Distinct().Contains(x.SID));
```

Let me know if this isn't what you intended. If this is the case, perhaps you have an SQL statement or similar that you are now trying to translate to C# LINQ, or can otherwise explain in plain English what this statement was meant to accomplish?